# xcopy via mapped network drive utf-8 file names. ret=4

Tags: php, cmd

I'm trying to use `xcopy` command to copy a  file with utf-8 file name from windows server(2008 R2 Standard) machine to another remote server(Windows 10), and I use `MapNetworkDrive` command to map the network drive.

```
try{
$WshNetwork = new COM("WScript.Network"); 
$WshNetwork->MapNetworkDrive("k:", SERVER_FOLDER, FALSE, SERVER_USER, SERVER_PASSWORD);
}catch(Exception $ex){}


echo f | xcopy "myFolder\тест.fbx" "k:\myFolder\тест.fbx"   (1)
```

As an output I get `out=0 File(s) copied ret=4`.

There are 3 important things I want to mention

1. When I use the above command with a file named with latin letters it works. For example `echo f | xcopy "myFolder\test.fbx" "k:\myFolder\test.fbx"` works fine.
2. When I try to use `(1)` command to copy the file(with non-latin letters) to another folder located on the same machine, everything successes.
   For example `echo f | xcopy "C:\\myFolder\тест.fbx" "C:\\myFolder\subFolder\тест.fbx"`
   this command also works fine.
3. When I try to copy via `(1)` the file from my local machine(windows 10) to the remote server(windows 10), it also works fine.

Why `(1)` command doesn't do the copy operation?

Comment: Sounds like the Server does not understand UTF file/folder names

Comment: RiggsFolly I've made another test, and edited my post according to it. Please look at it for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in my case was php version, I was using `php 7.0`, which doesn't work with unicode charactes. I don't know are there any other solutions, for earlier versions, but I've upgraded my `php` to `7.2` and problem was solved. Also I've found in other questions, that the problem disappears with `php 7.1` and upper versions.